# R: test what objects a function takes from the enclosing environment

Tags: r, function, debugging, testing, environment

When defining an R function, I sometimes miss that it relies on objects from the enclosing environment. Something like:

```
a <- 1
fn <- function(x) x + a
```

If this happens unintentionally, it can lead to problems which are difficult to debug.

Is there a simple way to test whether `fn` uses objects from the enclosing environment?

Something like:

```
test(fn=fn, args=list(x=1))
## --> uses 'a' from enclosing environment
```

Comment: Not a direct answer but maybe add `exists("a",envir = .GlobalEnv)` to your function and if `TRUE` then print the message that it is from for instance the global environment?

Comment: Thanks for the pointers to those questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility is to use the `findGlobals` function from the `codetools` package which is designed to:

> Finds global functions and variables used by a closure

This works in your example:

```
#install.packages('codetools')
codetools::findGlobals(fn)
[1] "+" "a"
```

If we define `a` inside the function, it goes away:

```
fn <- function(x) {
    a = 1
    x + a
}

codetools::findGlobals(fn)
[1] "{" "+" "="
```

But I haven't used it in anything more complex, so I can't say how accurate it will be with a more complex function. The docs come with the following caveat:

> The result is an approximation. R semantics only allow variables that might be local to be identified (and event that assumes no use of assign and rm).

Comment: I ended up using `codetools::findGlobals(fn, merge=FALSE)$variables`.